# How to make a button disappear and reappear after 'x' seconds?

Tags: javascript, html

How can I make this code;

```
 <input onclick="myFunction();" alt="click">Click Me!</button>
```

Hide for a few seconds, then re-appear after 'x' seconds? (This button works fine if that changes anything)

I'd like to stick with bare HTML, but if I need Javascript that's fine. No other solutions on SO work for me. Thanks.

edit:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="formalign.css">
      <script type="text/javascript" src="trinit5.js"></script>
      <button class="button" id="btn" input onclick="doSingle();" alt="Summon">Summon</button>
      <img id="canvas"></img>
      <div class="element"></div>
```

where do i embed the  part?

Comment: What are you trying to do is not understandable because you have started a **input tag(it is standalone tag)** and ended a **button tag(it is a paired tag)** and if you want a button than you must specify the **type attribute** in **input tag as button**

Comment: @Uzair so i do i just put `class="button"` in the middle or? thanks btw

Comment: What you need to do is there require to display timer caption on button rather than hide?

Comment: @Daniel check my answer and then if you dont understand ask me

Comment: @DanielGreen you are referencing a script called "trinit5.js" can you please add what this contains?

Comment: Trinit5.js only contains a piece of code that calls the doSingle() in my html code above

Comment: do you want to call both functions on same button click??

Answer (score 1):

input tag(it is standalone tag) and a button tag(it is a paired tag) and if you want a button than you can try two things:

1- assign button to the type attribute

```
<input type="button" id="btn" onclick="myFunction()" value="Click Me">
```

2-use a button tag it also has type attribute but by default button is assigned to type attribute

```
<button id="btn" onclick="myFunction()">Click Me!</button>
```

Here in the js i have written a function 
JS:

```
<script>
    function myFunction()
    {
      document.getElementById('btn').style.display ='none'; //first hide the button
      setTimeout(function(){ //using setTimeout function
      document.getElementById('btn').style.display ='inline'; //displaying the button again after 3000ms or 3 seconds
    }
    ,3000); 
    }
</script>
```

NOTE:
The setTimeout() method calls a function or evaluates an expression after a specified number of milliseconds.
Tip: 1000 ms = 1 second.
Tip: The function is only executed once

Answer (score 0):

Bare HTML won't do it I am afraid. You'll need a timer. Something like this maybe?

```html
<button id="btn" onclick="tempInvisible(this);">Click</button>
            
    <script>
    function tempInvisible(btn) {
    
        btn.style.display = 'none';
    
        setTimeout(function() { 
            btn.style.display = 'block';
        }, 10000);
    
    }    
        
    </script>
```

Comment: May consider changing to 2 seconds instead of 10 to make it clear quicker. Also could change your timeout to a variable called numOfSecondsToWait so the user understands easier.

Comment: What's not working? Is the button not disappearing? Or not coming back? Or...?

Answer (score 0):

---

Hello my friend,

This can be accomplished fairly easily using a setTimeout in JavaScript. I've created a code snippet below which you can use as an example. You can change the number after the comma (`1000`) in the setTimeout to reflect how many thousandths of a second you want the button to have disappeared for.

Cheers and best of luck to you!

```js
document.getElementById("button").onclick = function(){
  doSingle();
  document.getElementById("button").style.visibility = "hidden"
  setTimeout(function(){
    document.getElementById("button").style.visibility = "visible"
  }, 1000)
};
function doSingle() {
   // your function
};
```

```html
<button class="button" id="button" alt="Summon">Summon</button>
```

Comment: thanks, but the button tag for mine doesnt work, mine is       `<button class="button" id="button" input onclick="doSingle();" alt="Summon">Summon</button>`

Comment: Can you post the JavaScript?

Comment: you could try removing the `doSingle()` function call from the HTML completely, and place that inside of the `.onclick` event you copied from my post. I'll do an edit which includes that call.

Comment: take a look at it now :)

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't do anything when clicked, and it doesnt display a picture anymore

Comment: All we've done here is that now we're handling all the `onclick` functionality in the JavaScript instead of the html so we can add a `setTimeout` function inside of the `onclick` event

Comment: Yea, ive done everything, no luck. Hehe even the doSingle() function isn't even working, that's why I need to button

Comment: Looking more at the fiddle you posted, I can see more than one problem with your javascript. Unless I'm not seeing the whole script. Where are `imagesArray` and `lucknumber` declared (with `var` or `let`)? Also there is a comma instead of a semicolon after your `luck` array.

Comment: Idk, (yeah, that's the whole script) i got most of this from onlines because im a noob.

Comment: OK well it looks like it's just trying to randomly decide which array to then randomly select an image from, which you are attempting to set to the src property of the `window.canvas` object when the button is clicked, but I am not sure! And it's definitely not working. But as far as making a button disappear for a set amount of time, there are now multiple answers to your question that provide working solutions.